Flutter app on emulator work at first launch, but in subsequent launchs UI is not visible (even if present) until re-building or re-installing the app
I'm new to flutter and mobile app development (I started two weeks ago), and I have an issue with a flutterflow app.
When I start the application for the first time on emulator, everything render and work well, I can switch between pages and going back.
But when I close the app and try to launch it again from the emulator/run it again from command line, the application launch without error, but the UI is not visible (but still present).
I get a white screen, but if I click on certains UI elements (knowing their positions on the screen), they're triggered.
Clicking a navigation button load the attempted page, but the loaded page has the same problem, UI is present but not visible.
Cleaning the build with flutter clean and re running it don't solve the issue.
I found two ways to make app work again, for one launch:

I have to modify the code (e.g.: modifying a print content) and then re run it with flutter run without need of cleaning the build before.
I have to uninstall/reinstall the app on the emulator.

I'm not sure if it is an issue due to flutterflow code or an issue due to my emulator environment, I tried to make another simple flutterflow app, with one page, where i did not touch the code, and the same behaviour happen, when restarting the app, the UI is present but not visible.
For more context, I realized the UI with flutterflow, then downloaded the repository and made some logic on my side.
The application use a flutter webview to display a local html content (I replaced the flutterflow webview because I needed more control over the webview controller)
Rarely, when I have the issue and I reach the page that display the webview, the webview show the content (but the AppBar of the page is not visible)
The home screen when well rendered (the webview is not on this page):

The home screen when UI is present but not visible:

The emulator details:

Any hints would be welcome, does someone as already encountered this issue? If it is just an issue with the emulator env, it's not really an issue.
